# Using git describe --tags in codeship build script

Tags: git, build, codeship, code-push

I am trying to use `git describe --tags` to set the description of my builds in codeship. I have a custom shell script to do this, which works perfectly on my local environment. During the codeship build however, I get the error

```
Command failed: git describe --tags
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

I am struggling to find a similar problem and explanation on google. 
Is it not possible to run this command in the codeship build environment?

I have another script running that promotes my Staging builds to Production after a delay, and it uses the output of `git describe --tags` to check whether Production is ahead of Staging already (in case I need to promote urgently to Production).

thanks

Comment: Perhaps your build environment does a shallow clone, in which case there is no tag to see. Also, "--tags" is for lightweight un-annotated tags which are often seen to be "for local use, not for pushing to the server" so is it possible that the tags only exist on your machine and were never pushed to the central server?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try performing `git fetch --unshallow || true` in the script. As for the second half of your kind reply, that is unfortunately beyond my knowledge of git so thanks for educating me. I believe the tags are being sent to the central server, as the last time someone tagged the branch was before I joined the company and I have access to it.

Comment: Yes, I bet the `--unshallow` option is the culprit then. Of course it does mean that your build setup may be slower (depending on the size of your repo). I do not know of a workaround to this.

Comment: Think I will test the slowness and if it's unbearable, I guess I will have to find another solution. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Or you can use `git describe --tags --always`.